# How to perform Cross AWS account operation for eks:DescribeCluster action?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-iam, amazon-eks

I have 2 AWS accounts in this usecase,

- AWS Account A
- AWS Account B

Account A is where my EKS cluster resides and I would like to access this cluster from Account B specifically the API server endpoint and certificate data which I can get via eks:DescribeCluster action.

To be specific, my lambda runs in Account B and has to get the above data from the EKS cluster in Account A, to achieve this what is the best possible solution?

The approach that I took is performing chained sts:AssumeRole action to achieve the above i.e. Account B Lambda role assumes a role in Account A (this role TrustPolicy is updated to do that) and it works, however I would like to know what other alternate solution is available for this usecase.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create cross account policy for that:

Allow assume role for lambda:

```yaml
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::Account A:role/my-lambda-execution-role"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

And for you EKS:

```yaml
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::Account A:role/role-on-source-account"
    }
}
```

Assuming that role allows  `eks:DescribeCluster`

This reading explains s in more details: https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/lambda-function-assume-iam-role. Experiment with IAM roles until you get desired effect.